# Quarkus alternatives to spring-data-jdbc

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, quarkus, spring-data-jdbc, quarkus-panache

Default DAO layer / ORM framework in `Quarkus` is `Panache` (on top of Hibernate). It's very weird, since i didn't find any built-in integration for pluggable external L2 cache implementations like Redis.

Quarkus is called `cloud-native` but in real system it is very reckless to use default L2 cache impl, since it leads to inconsistent results when requests to service are distributed across multiple `Pod` instances (this issue is usually solved by external L2 cache).

So, i'm on a search to any other alternatives like `spring-data-jdbc`. I don't consider `JOOQ` since it doesn't provide such conveniences to work with simple Pojos and runtime resultsets auto-mapping like `sping-data-jdbc`.

Very appreciative to any suggestions.

**EDIT:**

found Quarkus <-> Spring-data integration. But it breaks the benefits of using Quarkus in terms of performance and hassle-free native-image compilation.

Comment: Quarkus does not provide a layer like Spring Data JDBC